# MongoDB authenticating as superuser always fails

Tags: mongodb, authentication

I have a fresh MongoDB 2.4.7 installation. I run commands below in first run:

```
db.getSiblingDB('admin').addUser({
    user: 'root', 
    pwd: 'root', 
    roles:['userAdminAnyDatabase', 'dbAdminAnyDatabase']
});
```

After restarting mongod using `--auth`, running `db.auth('root', 'root')` on any dbs fails including admin db.

How can i fix it to have a super user (root access) and add other users for dbs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to authenticate against the admin database and the MongoDB documentation recommend to use this user only to create new users and give appropriated permissions. But if you want to have a super user, also add the role readWriteAnyDatabase.

Comment: I think mongodb should make clear that admin != read/write roles. It confused me aswell.